# Matching on n products and sending a new worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two worksheets (ws): one is named "Order", the other is named "Data".

- In Order, there are four columns:
  order number, sap code, csc code, and product name with 10 lines (the number might rise in the future).
- In Data, I have more columns including
  date of stocks (A), sap code (B), csc code (C),  product name (E), line full (I).
  "Line full" is a conditional formatting check: if column I = 0 then the line will turn green and I know I ordered the product.

I would like to
(1) Create a new worksheet named B&L
(2) On this new worksheet I want to find the number of items listed on my order list with data from the "Data" ws.
(3) To retrieve the correct lines, I need a match on sap code (the common key between the two worksheets and only numbers) AND line full = 0, with the date of the row selected on the Data ws always being the earliest (i.e. if I have a date of 12/12 and 12/13, I want to select first date of the row of 12/12, and so on depending on the number I order).

Data worksheet
[image].

In the end, if I order three items with SAP code XXX and two items with SAP code YYYY, I need to find the following on my ws called "B/L"

```txt
Date  |SAP Code| CSC Code  |  Product Name
01/02   XXX       1234              XXXX
01/O2   XXX       1835             XXXX
02/02   xxx       1924              XXXX
01/02   yyy       1613             YYYY
03/06   yyyy      1512            YYYY
```

My code does not work in the loop.

```vb
Dim Worksheet As Worksheet
Dim Workbook As Workbook
Dim i As Integer
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Cell As Range

With Worksheets("Commande")
    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Sheets.Add.Name = "B&L"
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Date"
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SAP Code"
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "CSC Code"
Range("D1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Product Name"

'Here i m looking at finding what data i need to retrieve
Sheets("Order").Select
For i = 2 To Lastrow
    If Not Cells(i, 1) = 0 Then Sheets("Data").Select
'Here i want to get the data in the "Data"Ws and repeat it untill the number of rows of data i copy and past matches the number listed in the order
    Do Until Z = Sheets("Order").Cells(i, 1).Value
        For Each Cell In Range("I:I")
            If Cell.Value = 1 And Range("B").Cell.Value = Sheets("Order").Range("B").Cell.Value Then
                Range("A:C", "E:F").Copy Sheets("B/L").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(2)
            End If
        Next Cell
    Loop
Next
```

I have an error at

```
Cell.Value = 1 And Range("B").Cell.Value = Sheets("Commande").Range("B").Cell.Value
```

Comment: `Range("B").Cell.Value` is invalid. Maybe you meant `Cell.EntireRow.Columns("B").Value` or the same `Cells(Cell.Row, "B").Value`. Similarly, `Sheets("Commande").Range("B").Cell.Value` is invalid but have no idea how to fix it. You never mentioned `Commande`. What is its purpose?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. the Sheets("Commande") is Sheets("Order"), i forgot to translate it. If i was to put it in basic exel it would be [@[SAP Code] (from ws Oder) = [@[SAP Code] (from ws Data).

Comment: Are the `SAP Codes` numbers or text? Is `line full` 0, 1, or something else? Does *"with the date of line always being the earliest"* mean the topmost occurrence or something else? What does *"if I order 3 items with SAP code 1234"* mean? Does it mean that the `CSC Code` needs to be checked, too?

Comment: Why have you not included sample data (as text which can be copy/pasted) so someone can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your messages. Sorry, I updated the details with all your questions and comments. I also added a screenshot of the ws sheet (I did not find how to add excel file here).